# 2016 - Unpingco's Python for Probability, Statistics, and Machine Learning page 112

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning

I have a question
how do you go from here the expected risk function:

$$E_\theta (\theta - \hat\theta )^2 = \int (\theta - \hat\theta )^2 f(\textbf{x};\theta) \, dx $$

to here:
$$ \text{bias} = E_\theta(\hat\theta)-\theta    $$

Estimating using maximum likelihood. For parametric equation where unknown parameter $\theta$ should be estimated from set $\Theta$ with objective function $L(\theta, \hat\theta)=(\theta - \hat\theta )^2$. $\hat\theta(x)$ is an estimate of $\theta$ from $\textbf{x} $

See [page 112](https://books.google.com/books?id=KAvNCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA112) in *Python for Probability, Statistics, and Machine Learning* by José Unpingco.

Comment: The second thing you have written down is simply the definition of bias. You do not derive it from anywhere.. it is the definition. The first thing is an expression for the mean squared error, and has no direct bearing on it. (Although it makes sense they would be seen together as the mean squared error can be shown to be the bias squared plus the variance... this is probably the context in which you're seeing it.)

Comment: hopefully the edit makes more sense?

Comment: No it doesn't. You are asking how to derive a definition. You don't. It is a definition. The first thing has no bearing on it.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Just substituting the definition of bias. But how do you evaluate the integral to get bias square + variance?

Comment: I've given a derivation below. (It does not require the expectation value to be representable as an integral.)

Answer (score 3):

An estimator's bias is defined to be the average difference between the estimator and its true value. So your equation $\mathrm{bias}=E(\hat\theta) -\theta$ is simply the definition of bias, nothing more. As such it makes no such to ask how to derive it.

What is quite important is the relationship between the mean squared error $E((\theta-\hat\theta)^2)$ and bias is given by $$ E((\theta-\hat\theta)^2) = \theta^2-2\theta E(\hat\theta)+E(\hat\theta^2)\\=\theta^2-2\theta E(\hat\theta)+E(\hat\theta)^2+(E(\hat\theta^2)-E(\hat\theta)^2) \\=(E(\hat\theta)-\theta)^2+(E(\hat\theta^2)-E(\hat\theta)^2) \\=\operatorname{bias}(\hat\theta)^2+\operatorname{Var}(\hat\theta)$$

Comment: Why does low bias imply high variance? Bias being the difference between the estimated theta and the unknown actual theta. Wouldn't a smaller difference, meaning estimated theta is getting closer to actual theta imply a smaller variance?

Comment: @bottledatthesource "Bias being the difference between the estimated theta and the unknown actual theta." It is the *average* difference. The average difference can easily be zero while the realized differences are quite large in absolute value. In this case the estimator would be unbiased but high variance, and thus have a large mean-squared error entirely due to variance. Lower bias only implies higher variance if you're holding mean squared error fixed. It's possible for one estimator to have both larger bias and larger variance than another, provided its MSE is also larger.

Comment: @bottledatthesource To expand on the first point, note that difference is a signed quantity. Something with no bias but high variance will have large errors but they will be both too high and too low in such a way that they average out to zero. For instance, say you have a sample $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ and want to estimate the mean $\mu$. A silly way to do so would be to take $\hat \mu = X_1.$ This is an unbiased estimator, cause by definition, $E(X_1)=\mu.$ But it is much higher variance than the more sensible estimator $\frac{X_1+\ldots +X_n}{n}$

Comment: Great. That makes sense.